# WM_COMMAND WM_NOTIFY custom notification code

Tags: winapi, mfc

I wish to define a new nofication id that will be used in WM_COMMAND messages of my subclassed control. But I failed to find any rules of creating user control-defined notification codes.

Comment: do you mean user defined message? if so use WM_USER + 1

Comment: no, consider the following code:
PostMessage( WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM( GetDlgCtrlID(), MY_CUSTOM_USER_NOTIFICATION_ID ), subclassButtonWnd );

I need the rules that will describe what id number i can use for MY_CUSTOM_USER_NOTIFICATION_ID

Comment: #define MY_CUSTOM_USER_NOTIFICATION_ID WM_USER + 1

Comment: Are you sure? Could you please provide any MSDN confirmation link?

Comment: @Jeeva is confused. Notification IDs and message IDs are not the same. My instinct is that you can't use `WM_COMMAND` for custom notifications and instead should use a custom message, in the `WM_USER` range.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See technical note 20, 21 and 22 on that:

- [TN020: ID Naming and Numbering Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx)
- [TN021: Command and Message Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt2c310k.aspx)
- [TN022: Standard Commands Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11861byt.aspx)

Short answer: pick a number in the range 0x8000 - 0xDFFF .

Comment: Nitpick: In the future, please remember to remove the parenthetical version-specifiers at the end of your MSDN links. That will cause the link to automatically point to the *most recent* version of the documentation. The user can change the version using the "Other Versions" drop-down at the top of the page if required.